# D3.js executing in different manner

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I came from `javascript` background and I started `d3.js` While practice I written the following code.

html code :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="firstP"></p>
  <p id="secondP"></p>
  <p id="thirdP"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

js code :

```
var theData = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
       .data(theData)
       .enter()
       .append("p")
       .text( function (d) { return d; } );
console.log(p);
```

My motivation was, I want to append `p` nodes in between `#firstP,#secondP,#thirdP` elements. but after I execute above I am getting `null` how `d3` handling this I didn't understand.

For my testing, I removed last `p` node from html file, the output coming 2 null values and 1 `p` node appending with corresponding data(`3`) .

I didn't understand how `d3.js` will handle this things.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Could you make a JSFiddle to demonstrate?

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you're matching the data to the existing `p` elements. That is, your selection contains three `p` elements and your data contains three elements. Those are matched to the elements you've selected and the enter selection is empty. See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) for more information on how selections work.

What you're trying to do isn't all that easy with D3 because you usually don't insert elements at specific positions, but append them to the DOM. However, you can use [`.insert()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#insert) to achieve it. This is highly contrived though and I don't recommend that you do this in practice.

```
var theData = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var names = ["firstP", "secondP", "thirdP"];
d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(theData, function(d) { return d; })
   .enter()
    .insert("p", function(d, i) { return d3.select("#" + names[i]).node(); })
   .text( function (d) { return d; } );
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xo75wxh7/).

Comment: If he's just trying to append the data to the existing elements as their text, that's actually *really easy* to do: `d3.select('body').selectAll('p').data(theData).text(function(d){ return d; })` No need for an enter selection, since the elements already exist.

Comment: Yep, and just appending the new elements after the existing ones would be really easy as well. It's the in between that makes it difficult.